# is there a way to split commands without using tee?

Tags: macos, terminal

tee outputs the input to a command and stdout. i would like to split the input but without the contents sent to stdout.

like

```sh
command1 | tee >(command2) >(command3)
```

i tried

```sh
command1 | >(command2) >(command3)
```

but this doesn't forward the output of command1 to either command2 or command3

Comment: Are you looking for `command1 | tee >(command2) | command3`?

Comment: Redirect stdout to /dev/null.  Ie... `command | tee file.out >/dev/null`

Comment: @GordonDavisson !!! yee haa that's the one.. so i guess that stdout can get picked up by a command instead. also output to file can be substituted for a command? as > is meant to be to file but it goes to the command parenthesis. it's hard to find what these symbols can do

Comment: @yarns I think you're misunderstanding what stdout is. Each command has its own stdout; by default, they're inherited from the shell, so they'll all be directed at the terminal, but redirections change that. In the command I gave, command1's stdout is the pipe to tee, tee's stdout is the pipe to command3, and since command3 doesn't have a redirect its stdout is the terminal (inherited from the shell). command2 is more complicated; bash and ksh both consider it part of the pipeline (along with tee), so its stdout goes to the pipe to command3. But zsh doesn't, so it goes to the terminal.

Comment: @GordonDavisson yes definately thanks. being self taught (and not focused on shells and terminals) i ended up missing alot of fundamentals. funny how i can come across those terms many times in a day and not actually know what they mean :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer was tested using `zsh` version 5.7.1 and `bash` version 3.2.57. The version of macOS was Catalina (10.15.7). A good reference is the [Bash Redirections Cheat Sheet](https://acm.cs.uic.edu/wiki/_media/bash-redirections-cheat-sheet.pdf), which I assume (mostly?) works with `zsh`.

### A `zsh` Answer

Evidentially, `zsh` has a [multios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76401839/how-can-zsh-handle-multiple-redirections) feature. This allows a redirection to be used multiple times, which can eliminate the need to use the `tee` command.

In your case, you only want to redirect standard output twice, so the syntax of one such method would be as follows.

```
command1 > >(command2) | command3
```

Note that the above line executes `command1` and `command2` in subshells. The line below accomplishes the same redirections, but instead executes `command2` and `command 3` in subshells.

```
command1 > >(command2) > >(command3)
```

Actually, `zsh` can redirect the output to as many commands as there are available file descriptors. For example, if you wanted four, then the syntax would be as follows.

```
command1 > >(command2) > >(command3) > >(command4) > >(command5)
```

### Two `bash` and `zsh` Answers

If you what something that is both `bash` and `zsh` compatible, then you can use the `tee` command. [Gordon Davisson](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/427/gordon-davisson) has already posted a [comment](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/696697) suggesting the following answer.  Here, the file descriptor associated with the pipe used as standard input to `command2` is chosen automatically. With `bash` the automatically assigned file descriptors start at 63 and decrease in value. With `zsh`, the automatically assigned file descriptors start at 11 and increase in value.

```
command1 | tee >(command2) | command3
```

If you wanted four, then the syntax would be as follows.

```
command1 | tee >(command2) >(command3) >(command4) | command5
```

My answer involves explicitly stating which file descriptor to use, as shown below.

```
command1 | tee /dev/fd/3 3> >(command2) | command3
```

If you wanted four, then the syntax would be as follows.

```
command1 | tee /dev/fd/3 /dev/fd/4 /dev/fd/5 3> >(command2) 4> >(command3) 5> >(command4) | command5
```

### Equivalence Between the Two `bash` and `zsh` Answers

As already stated, the line below works in both `bash` and `zsh`.

```
command1 | tee >(command2) >(command3) >(command4) | command5
```

In `bash`, the line would be equivalent to the following (assuming the file descriptors are not already in use.)

```
command1 | tee /dev/fd/63 /dev/fd/62 /dev/fd/61 63> >(command2) 62> >(command3) 61> >(command4) | command5
```

This can be confirmed by entering the command lines given below.

```
fun(){ echo $@ >&2;}
:|fun >(:) >(:) >(:)|:
```

In `zsh`, the line would be equivalent to the following (assuming the file descriptors are not already in use).

```
command1 | tee /dev/fd/14 /dev/fd/15 /dev/fd/16 14> >(command2) 15> >(command3) 16> >(command4) | command5
```

This can be confirmed by entering the same two command lines given to confirm bash.

Comment: is file descriptor like a variable thread? so the syntax you declare your `fd`s and reference them later. I don't understand why they use the term `file descriptor` when it can go to a command. also i thought standard output was just to print it in the terminal but this probably opens up alot of doors now thanks!

Comment: cheat sheet iz magic thanks.. if it works with zsh

Comment: The `command1 > >(command2) | (command3)` version depends on zsh's multios feature, where zsh itself basically emulates `tee`. I don't know of any other shell that has this feature. BTW, in the first examples, using `/dev/fd#` and the redirects is unnecessary, you can just use `>(somecommand)` directly in the arg list, and it'll pass the appropriate FD or named pipe (depending on what the OS supports) as an argument.

Comment: @GordonDavisson: Base on your comment, I updated my answer. Thanks.

Comment: yarns: I do not know what a "variable thread" is. The custom file descriptors used in my answer are associated with anonymous fifos (pipes). Anonymous means a fifo does not have a filename. The `tee` command requires filenames as parameters. In such cases, a file descriptor can be preceded by `/dev/fd/` to give the file descriptor a filename.

Comment: no, forget that, It made sense to my limited understanding at the time. TLDR: i just made up variable thread to mean like defining a variable in a program, then later referencing that variable as an expression, to create separate threads (or processing streams) inline. it doesn't make sense because i'm still learning the terms used here in the answers.. thanks so much everyone!

Comment: @DavidAnderson by subshell you mean like another process thread? like same as if you ran the command separately in another terminal window?

Comment: A process thread and a command ran in a separate Terminal window are both real physical entities. A subshell is either a fork of the current shell or an emulation of a fork of the current shell by the current shell. This makes a subshell more of an abstraction.

Comment: The purpose of mentioning subshell in my answer was to point out the following. The output from `unset x y z; x=10 > >(y=20) | z=30; echo $x $y $z` would be `30`. In other words, only the assignment of `z=30` survives, because the `x=10` and `y=20` assignments are completed in different subshells. The `z=30` assignment was not completed in a subshell.

Comment: This differs from `unset x y z; x=10 > >(y=20) > >(z=30); echo $x $y $z`, where the output would be `10`.

Comment: very very nice 